# How to set up many to many relationship correctly with EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I have some issues with getting my many to many relationship to work. I have two tables, Beestje and Accessoire, and I want to show its contents.

This are my tables:
Beestje:

```
public class Beestje
{
    public Beestje()
    {
        this.Accessoires = new HashSet<Accessoire>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Naam { get; set; }

    public String Type { get; set; }

    public int Prijs { get; set; }

    public String Afbeelding { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Accessoire> Accessoires { get; set; }
}
```

Accessoire:

```
public class Accessoire
{
    public Accessoire()
    {
        this.Beestjes = new HashSet<Beestje>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Naam { get; set; }

    public double Prijs { get; set; }

    public String Afbeelding { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Beestje> Beestjes { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I retrieve the contents from the Beestje table and return it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Beestjes()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application beestjes page";

        List<Beestje> beestjes;

        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            beestjes = context.Beestjes.ToList();

            return View(beestjes);
        }
    }
```

When I print it like this there are no problems:

```
@model IEnumerable<BeestjeOpJeFeestje.Models.Beestje>

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var a in Model)
    {
        <li>@a.Naam</li>
    }
</ul>
```

But when I print it like this I get an error:

```
@model IEnumerable<BeestjeOpJeFeestje.Models.Beestje>

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var a in Model)
    {
        <li>@a.Naam</li>
        foreach (var b in a.Accessoires)
        {
            <li>@b.Naam</li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

It goes wrong at the part where I call the a.Accessoires.
The error is:
"System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.'"

Does someone know the correct way, and would be willing to provide me the right code, or give me some directions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

MyContext

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext() : base("name=Local")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<Beestje> Beestjes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Accessoire> Accessoires { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

MyContextInitializer

```
public class MyContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 1, Naam = "Aap", Type = "Jungle", Prijs = 150, Afbeelding = "Content/images/aap.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 2, Naam = "Olifant", Type = "Jungle", Prijs = 250, Afbeelding = "Content/images/olifant.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 3, Naam = "Zebra", Type = "Jungle", Prijs = 200, Afbeelding = "Content/images/zebra.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 4, Naam = "Leeuw", Type = "Jungle", Prijs = 250, Afbeelding = "Content/images/leeuw.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 5, Naam = "Hond", Type = "Boerderij", Prijs = 75, Afbeelding = "Content/images/doggo.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 6, Naam = "Ezel", Type = "Boerderij", Prijs = 150, Afbeelding = "Content/images/donkey.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 7, Naam = "Koe", Type = "Boerderij", Prijs = 100, Afbeelding = "Content/images/koe.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 8, Naam = "Eend", Type = "Boerderij", Prijs = 50, Afbeelding = "Content/images/duck.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 9, Naam = "Kuiken", Type = "Jungle", Prijs = 35, Afbeelding = "Content/images/kuiken.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 10, Naam = "Pinguin", Type = "Sneeuw", Prijs = 175, Afbeelding = "Content/images/pingwing.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 11, Naam = "IJsbeer", Type = "Sneeuw", Prijs = 300, Afbeelding = "Content/images/ijsbeer.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 12, Naam = "Zeehond", Type = "Sneeuw", Prijs = 200, Afbeelding = "Content/images/zeehond.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 13, Naam = "Kameel", Type = "Woestijn", Prijs = 175, Afbeelding = "Content/images/kameel.png" });
            context.Beestjes.Add(new Beestje() { Id = 14, Naam = "Slang", Type = "Sneeuw", Prijs = 125, Afbeelding = "Content/images/slang.png" });

            var accessoire1 = new Accessoire() { Naam = "Banaan", Prijs = 0.50 };
            accessoire1.Beestjes.Add(context.Beestjes.Find(1));
            context.Accessoires.Add(accessoire1);

            var accessoire2 = new Accessoire() { Naam = "Zadel", Prijs = 4.50 };
            accessoire2.Beestjes.Add(context.Beestjes.Find(3));
            context.Accessoires.Add(accessoire2);

            var accessoire3 = new Accessoire() { Naam = "Krukje", Prijs = 5 };
            accessoire3.Beestjes.Add(context.Beestjes.Find(4));
            context.Accessoires.Add(accessoire3);

            var accessoire4 = new Accessoire() { Naam = "Zweep", Prijs = 2.50 };
            accessoire4.Beestjes.Add(context.Beestjes.Find(4));
            context.Accessoires.Add(accessoire4);

            var accessoire5 = new Accessoire() { Naam = "Bal", Prijs = 2.50 };
            accessoire5.Beestjes.Add(context.Beestjes.Find(5));
            accessoire5.Beestjes.Add(context.Beestjes.Find(12));
            context.Accessoires.Add(accessoire5);

            var accessoire6 = new Accessoire() { Naam = "Dansschoenen", Prijs = 3.00 };
            accessoire6.Beestjes.Add(context.Beestjes.Find(10));
            context.Accessoires.Add(accessoire6);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web stack, not a data access library. Are you using EF or EF Core? Which version? Please post the definition of `MyContext`, that's where the relations are configured

Comment: Yes you are correct, i forgot to include that. I am using EF6. I included the MyContext in the question now.

Comment: As for the error itself, it says nothing about relations. It says the code tried to use an ObjectContext instance that was already disposed. Recent versions of EF use DbContext, not ObjectContext. Are you accessing ObjectContext explicitly somewhere in your code? Perhaps trying to use a UDF?

Comment: I searched my project for ObjectContext, but I am not using it anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the fact that for each `Beestje`, the `Accessoires` property does not get loaded until you try to access it in the View, and at that moment the `MyContext` has already been disposed.

The solution is to tell EF to load them immediately by using `.Include()`, which is known as 'eager loading':

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    beestjes = context.Beestjes
        .Include("Accessoires")
        .ToList();

    return View(beestjes);
}
```

For reference, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data